# asp.net access user control in vb class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, casting, user-controls

i have a usercontrol named filebox (which wraps a fileupload and some related stuff)

in a certain .net class i have need to use this type as a ctype

but i cant seem to call ctype(aobject,filebox)

or either ctype(aobject,Controls_filebox) (which is the correct name)

how can i convert an object to this type?

thanks a million!

Comment: Where did you put the control?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the class' namespace.

It's probably in the `ASP` namespace; you can check in the Object Browser.

You can change the namespace by adding `Class="My.Namespace.Filebox"` in the `<%@ Control` directive.

Comment: hi. your fast! thanks. in the control directive i added classname="mycontrols.filebox" (there is no "class" attribute.  the contol now shows in object browser as "controls_filebox" but cannot get any info about it. it says that the info is hidden.    also in my code i still cant access it.    i dont even have a "asp" namespace. please advise

Comment: What namespace is it appear in in the Object Browser?

Comment: how can i know? all i get is "Controls_FileBox". when i click it nothing shows up in the right pane or anywhere else

Comment: It appears directly under your project?

Comment: now its not showing up at all. but when it did it did not even show under something. where can i send u a picture?

Comment: Try moving the .ascx file to the App_Code folder.

Comment: wait. now it does show up twice once as mynamespace.FileBox and also as controls_filebox but neither are accessible in the code. they are under \562fbb05\_shadow\d0caab30\2208506753\30128110\App_Web_filebox.ascx.cc671b29.2as3p7aw.dll if that means anything to you!

Comment: this is strange. when the filebox.ascx file is open onscreen then they show up in the object browser. the minute i close the file they disappear. And i cannot put the ascx file in app_code as it brings a compiler error that it cannot be in the special app_code folder. any advice?